# All Threads Blocked on socket IO when using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

I am experiencing a very frustrating problem.

Basically I have a huge amount of sql update statements to perform on a mysql db using JDBC. To do this, in the time required, I am using Java's Executor Service with a fixed thread pool like so:

```
ExecutorService executor =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

Each thread calls the run method of another class, I have and in that class, an sql update operation is performed.

But, it is running extremely slow and JProfiler has revealed that all the threads block on socket IO. I thought that mysql would be able to handle multiple update statements concurrently.

Any ideas on how to get around this problem?

Note I have 10 available processors on my machine.

Below is a screenshot of the Thread History screen from JProfiler. The Light Blue colour here indicates that the thread is in Net I/O(The thread is waiting to write data to a socket).

[image]

Comment: How are you connecting to mysql ? Using connection pooling or opening and closing connections in each thread?

Comment: Well each thread has a Connection object, and it connects to to mysql using the following code:Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("");

Comment: Unless your MySQL is performing CPU bound operations (and you have more than 10 CPUs) some of these operations will block on wait for shared resources e.g. your disk.  MySQL can handle 10 connections, but there is no guarantee it will be faster than using 1 depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Looks like you are creating connection in every thread. I would suggest to put a breakpoint in the thread class and step through. This will let you know where precisely the thread is blocked. It could be on getting connection, executing statements. I would also suggest to look at mysql logs.

Comment: Post your code. If you open a new connection every time you need to execute a single statement, it's not surprising that it's extremely slow.

Comment: Peek at your mysql server and see what it's doing, e.g. by running the `mysqladmin pr` command.

Comment: Blocking on socket I/O doesn't mean a lot. It is unlikely it is doing actual I/O on the socket; rather, it is probably just waiting for a response from the server. You say the thread is waiting to write data, but are you sure? Do you know it is not waiting to read? Look on the server and see what is going on. It may also be your updates are contending and locking the same rows, which will slow the whole thing down.